# R Markdown Error - closure is not subsettable withCallingHandlers -> withVisible-> eval ->hist

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm having a problem saving this file as a pdf via markdown. Everything saves up until I get to the chunk with `hist()`, where I get the error `closure is not subsettable withCallingHandlers -> withVisible-> eval ->hist` I tried looking around and checked if variables/objects were saved as popular functions. Any help would be nice!

````
```{r eval=FALSE}  
Study<-read.csv("Data.csv")
```

Recode Age column into oridinal variable and store into new column
```{r eval=FALSE} 
Study$Age2 <- as.factor( # Define new column as a factor/categorical variable
  case_when(Study$s1 <= 65 ~ 'Young-Old',
            between(Study$s1, 66, 75) ~ 'Med-Old',
            between(Study$s1, 76, 85) ~ 'Old',
            Study$s1 >= 86 ~ 'Old-Old'
  )
)
```
Conduct histogram to illustrate patients' age distribution
```{r, echo=FALSE}
hist(as.numeric(Study$Age2), main = "Age Distribution", xlab = "Age Range")
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that the first two code chunks are not evaluated and so the data are not available for chunk #3. 
So, if you change your code to

````
```{r}  
Study<-read.csv("Data.csv")
```

Recode Age column into oridinal variable and store into new column
```{r} 
Study$Age2 <- as.factor( # Define new column as a factor/categorical variable
 case_when(Study$s1 <= 65 ~ 'Young-Old',
            between(Study$s1, 66, 75) ~ 'Med-Old',
            between(Study$s1, 76, 85) ~ 'Old',
            Study$s1 >= 86 ~ 'Old-Old'
  )
)
```
````

the render process is running completely.

Nevertheless, this problem is rather strange, because you have no comma between r and eval = F, so `eval = F` is the name of the chunk, but will not be evaluated too. If you don't want to include the code in your output-file, you can add `{r, include = F}`.

Comment: Thanks! Let me take a look at it!

Comment: It works. And in response to your comment, it was rather strange that I was able to run the code in chunks... no idea why and how

Comment: If you run the chunk in the RMD file, it all works fine. The eval = F command is just responsible if you render the document.